# theming with polymerthemes.com, core-elements, paper-elements and core-style

Tags: polymer

I seem to be missing something when it comes to applying themes to my polymer app. I started with a theme.css from polymerthemes.com and a test app. All worked well.

Then I started breaking it up into separate polymer elements and brining in some of my existing elements (built from paper and core elements). The styling stopped working as it hit the shadow dom boundary.

To fix it, I put `body /deep/` *in front of every style in themes.css!!*

Works but I can't imagine that is the way this is supposed to work.

I had a look at `core-style` and that looks like exactly what is needed, but none of the core and paper elements seem to use it. Am I missing something or is this still very much a work in progress?

It would be great if we could get to a point where instead of downloading a theme.css and putting `body /deep/` everywhere, that we could simply add a bower (or pub) dependency on a theme and it would work out of the box. Is this realistic?

Answer (score 2):

I'm part of the team behind polymerthemes.com.

Your solution should work fine, however we'll be releasing an update shortly with the default CSS download piercing all shadow boundaries.

Bower integration is coming too (it's been a highly requested feature), stay tuned.

EDIT: All themes on polymerthemes.com now pierce all shadow boundaries.

We've also added support for bower, basic usage:

`bower install polymer-themes`

or to add as a dependency to your app's bower.json file:

`bower install --save polymer-themes`

Comment: Thanks. I look forward to trying the new version. Do you plan anything around `core-style`?

Comment: `core-style` is not on our immediate radar, but we are looking at it. Currently our focus is to provide simple, drop-in themes for Polymer's UI elements.